# Why "git cvsimport" only returns an empty Git repo?

Tags: git, cvs

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.2 with Git 1.7.8.2 installed using Homebrew, cvsps 2.2b1, and git-cvsimport.

I worked with a Subversion repository of a Web site project sometime ago which I've successfully converted into a Git repo. While I haven't worked on the project, a colleague who could not access and use Subversion, but had the latest checkout, saved his changes in a CVS repository.

I would like to convert his CVS commits and apply them on my Git repo. But I have no experience in CVS; as I only worked with Subversion and Git before.

For now, I'm only trying to convert his CVS repo into Git. (Perhaps I'll use a git merge or git rebase later to get the converted Subversion and CVS repositories together into one Git repo. But I'm not at that point yet.)

He sent me a compressed tarball of his CVS "repo." When I untar it, I get one directory matching the name of the project, with files in it matching each file of project, but with a ",v" at the end of each name for versioning. I assume the tarball I got is only a module for a CVS repository, which I think should be sufficient.

Here's the structure of my files:

- ~/Sites/CVSROOT/

  - sitename/

    - .cvsignore,v
    - index.html,v
    - images/
    - ...

The commands I use to convert the CVS module into a Git repo is the following:

```
$ cd ~/Sites
$ rm -fr sitename # Make way for new git repo of same name.
$ git cvsimport -v -d ~/Sites -C sitename sitename
```

This is what it outputs:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/remi/Sites/sitename/.git/
Running cvsps...
cvs_direct initialized to CVSROOT /Users/remi/Sites
cvs rlog: Logging sitename
cvs rlog: Logging sitename/.git
cvs rlog: Logging sitename/.git/hooks
cvs rlog: Logging sitename/.git/info
cvs rlog: Logging sitename/.git/objects
cvs rlog: Logging sitename/.git/objects/info
cvs rlog: Logging sitename/.git/objects/pack
cvs rlog: Logging sitename/.git/refs
cvs rlog: Logging sitename/.git/refs/heads
cvs rlog: Logging sitename/.git/refs/tags
DONE; creating master branch
fatal: refs/heads/origin: not a valid SHA1
fatal: master: not a valid SHA1
fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
checkout failed: 32768
```

When I get into the directory of the new Git repo, doing `git log` yields `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`.

Is there something I'm missing? Are there other files I need from my colleague's CVS repo server?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I suggest to use this http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2git.html cvsps is not supported - doesnt work with branches and just plain old doesnt work IMHO

Comment: I'll answer with more details later, but for the time being, your suggestion worked. Thanks!

Comment: Cool - I moved it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use this http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2git.html. cvsps is not supported - doesnt work with branches and just plain old doesnt work IMHO

Comment: Thank you, Adrian Cornish, for your comment on my question.

I gave up at installing cvs2git when I encountered problems with a missing DB library for Python. But after reading your advice, I braved the installation pains, and it worked beautifully.

With the instructions at the page linked below, I was able to create a new Git repo, and then merge the commits with my older Git repo converted from Subversion using "git cherry-pick first-commit-id-in-cvs-after-last-in-svn..last-commit-id-in-cvs".

http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2git.html

Comment: Glad it helped you out Remino